# Simple RequireJS test not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Im new to RequireJS and testing something out to get my feet wet. I'm trying to have require load in base Angular, and then manually lad in Angular UI Bootstrap. However, when I do this, UI Bootstrap complains that `angular is not defined`, meaning my loading from Require doesn't seem to be setup properly.

My folder structure:

```
app
 |js
   |main.js
 |index.html
```

Basic HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myUrl/requirejs" data-main="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="myUrl/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

Main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths : {
        'angular' : 'myUrl/1.3.4/angular.min.js',
        'jquery' : 'myUrl/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
    },
    shim : {
        'angular' : {
            exports : 'angular',
            deps: ["jquery"]
        }
    }
});
```

So why isnt Angular loaded in properly for use later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code you show in your question, you have some modules that are meant to be loaded with RequireJS, namely `angular` and `jquery`. And then you load `myUrl/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` with a `script` element. Presumably, this script should use the `angular` module. **This cannot work.** You should make `ui-bootstrap-tpls` compatible with RequireJS by giving it a shim, just like any other non-AMD module you want to load with RequireJS. And then you'll have to kick off the actual loading with a call to `require` to tell what module must be loaded.

I also note you have not configured RequireJS to load Bootstrap's JS code.

Answer (score 1):

Shims or require config does not load any scripts. Scripts are loaded when you require it.